# Can't see created databases

Tags: phpmyadmin, easyphp

I've got two problems with EasyPHP (probably related).

1) If I create the database in PhpMyAdmin I can't see it in the navigation panel or in the "Database" page. the database exists because I can make query on it and it conflicts with other CREATE instructions (using the same name). I supposed it was a configuration (permission?) problem so...

2) Going to tray icon, right click on easyPHP icon, then "Configuration->PhpMyAdmin" I obtain "Object not found" error for the URL `http://127.0.0.1/home/mysql/`.

I use win8.

Thank you.

EDIT: 
I tried to update to PhpMyAdmin 4.1.12, but nothing happened.

Comment: It looks more like an issue with the use of a program, then an actual programming issue?

Comment: @Nanne, yes, but the forum of easyPHP does not exist anymore, so I have to ask here for assistence (see http://www.easyphp.org/forums/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the solution! In `config.inc.php` configuration file, I changed this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|test|phpmyadmin)';
```

With:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|test|phpmyadmin)$';
```

Now it works fine!

Comment: This just worked for me too! All I did was create a database through phpMyAdmin and when I went to export it, the database in question didn't show while others did. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I've just faced this problem for the first time. This solution really amazes me. Why does phpmyadmin create this kind of issue lol?

Answer (score 0):

if you create a database with the string "test" in it, it will hide, because of the line in the accepted answer. I removed "test" from this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(mysql|information_schema|performance_schema|test|phpmyadmin)$';
```

and the database showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you gave didn't really work in my case so I tried **commenting** the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = ' '` line, as its only purpose is to hide the "default" DBs used to make the whole system function correctly. When I did, all the databases showed in the *PhpMyAdmin* dashboard.

**DISCLAIMER:** Using this method allows you to `DROP` and `ALTER` system databases, which can result in *PhpMyAdmin* not working anymore. If you ever need to comment this line, be sure not to ALTER any of the said databases afterwards.

**Reminder:** the databases which must remain untouched are :

- information_schema
- mysql
- performance_schema
- test
- phpmyadmin